# High and latent CPU usage with OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, nvidia

Essentially, I'm using OpenCV's OpenCL filters to postprocess the OpenGL framebuffer. At a glimbse, everything works nice and smoothly at real-time with mouse interaction. However, when I render a steady scene --- that is when the process should go to idle --- I realize high single core CPU usage, which latently follows the last interaction few seconds or even half minute behind. In fact, the CPU usage is around all the time, but not in "my" thread (so it's not blocking anything) but rather running in background at NVidia's nvopencl.dll.

My system is:

```
Windows 10 64-bit
Intel Core i7-6820HQ
NVidia Quadro M4000M
nvopencl.dll as NVidia CUDA 9.0.176 OpenCL 1.2 Driver
Visual Studio 2015
```

I have built OpenCV myself and the problem is also reproducible without the OpenCV, just makes it easier to replicate. It'd be an awful lot of code to reproduce all of it, but I managed to wrap it as follows. (The sample of course doesn't show whether any image filtering was completed, but in the actual application I can easily verify this indeed happening after each `finish`-call):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/ocl.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"


// Retrieves timing information for the specified process.
// millisecond units like GetTickCount()
double GetProcessTickCount(void )
{
    FILETIME c, e, k, u;
    GetProcessTimes(GetCurrentProcess(),&c,&e,&k,&u);
    ULARGE_INTEGER a,b;
    a.LowPart = k.dwLowDateTime;
    a.HighPart = k.dwHighDateTime;
    b.LowPart = u.dwLowDateTime;
    b.HighPart = u.dwHighDateTime;
    double t = 1000.0 * (double)( a.QuadPart + b.QuadPart ) * 100.0e-9;
    return t;
}
int main( void )
{
    // read any image file
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("face1.png",cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    std::cout << "Image size: "<< src.size() << std::endl;

#if 0
    cv::Mat dst;
    cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(false); // explicit not to use OpenCL
    std::cout << "Without OpenCL" << std::endl;
    double t = cv::getTickCount();
    for ( int i=0;i<500;++i )
    {
        cv::bilateralFilter( src, dst, 15, 32.0, 8.0 );
    }
#else
    // copy into a UMat
    cv::UMat u, d;
    src.copyTo( u );
    // force using OpenCL
    cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);
    double t = cv::getTickCount();
    for ( int i=0;i<500;++i )
    {
        // do bilateral filtering (on OpenCL, verify this by the debugger)
        cv::bilateralFilter( u, d, 15, 32.0, 8.0 );
        // finish the work
        cv::ocl::finish();
        // render the result, the finish is not required, but with OpenGL texture objects it kinda was...
        // ...
    }
#endif
    t = cv::getTickCount()-t;
    std::cout << "t=" << (t/cv::getTickFrequency()) << " seconds, fps=";
    std::cout << 500.0/(t/cv::getTickFrequency()) << std::endl;

    double cpuTime = 0;
    t = cv::getTickCount(); // wait time starts
    for ( ; ; std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(1) ) )
    {
        double time = GetProcessTickCount();
        // once we figure out CPU no more working on this process, we finish
        // !! note, first 1 second wait happens anyway
        if ( time - cpuTime > 2.0 ) // 2 ms to play safe
        {
            cpuTime = time;
        }else
            break;      
    }
    t = cv::getTickCount()-t; // wait time ends
    std::cout << "about to exit after waiting " << (t/cv::getTickFrequency()) << " seconds" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the prints with

```
Image size: [640 x 960]
t=2.78591 seconds, fps=179.474
about to exit after waiting 21.0132 seconds
Press any key to continue . . .
```

and without OpenCL

```
Image size: [640 x 960]
Without OpenCL
t=10.9039 seconds, fps=45.8551
about to exit after waiting 1.00018 seconds
Press any key to continue . . .
```

And here is the profiler report (clTryout is the name of the sample program):
[image]

And the question is, of course, how to fix this issue?

*** UPDATE ***

I couldn't reproduce this issue on my mobile platform w/ Intel i5-8250U and Intel OpenCL driver. Note that the wait time is 1 second as supposed. Looks like an NVidia issue.

```
Image size: [640 x 960]
[ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...
[ INFO:0] Preparing OpenCL cache configuration for context: Intel_R__Corporation--Intel_R__UHD_Graphics_620--23_20_16_4849
t=8.36944 seconds, fps=59.7411
about to exit after waiting 1.00269 seconds
Press any key to continue . . .
```

vs.

```
Image size: [640 x 960]
Without OpenCL
t=39.0353 seconds, fps=12.8089
about to exit after waiting 1.00778 seconds
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The question has been asked before, but not solved 
[Unexpected CPU utilization with OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525489/unexpected-cpu-utilization-with-opencl)

Comment: How about replacing `finish()` with `flush()` and calling `finish()` one time after the loop?

Comment: @doqtor within the actual application, I first `clFinish` to make the OpenGL object available (it is converted from `image2d_t` to a buffer), then `cv::ocl::finish` to have the filter completed (I thought using the same context would queue all commands in one, but apparently not), and finally after copying the filter's destination buffer into `image2d_t` that will be rendered. Last `clFinish` I can replace by `clFlush`, but this didn't change the situation. `glFinish` is called consequtively while rendering the scene.

Comment: I was referring to `cv::ocl::finish()` inside the loop to replace it with `cv::ocl::flush()` (I suspect OpenCV has got that OpenCL equivalent of clFlush), so that each iteration isn't blocked inside the loop, which probably increases the CPU usage. Then after the loop a blocking call to `cv::ocl::finish()` would be required.

Comment: @doqtor I didn't readily find `cv::ocl::flush()`, but just commenting out the inside-loop `cv::ocl::finish` and adding one after the loop doesn't change the situation for this sample code. The fps doesn't increase either, so I guess the filter is finished without the explicit call. The tail (20 seconds of CPU work) remains.